# Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy with img base64 from canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, safari, cross-domain

This is my problem:
I have 2 canvases `C1` and `C2` and 3 `<img>` tags `I1`, `I2`, and `I3`.

First, I load `I1` into `C1`.
Next, I set an image into `C1` and then `I2.src = C1.toDataURL();` (PROBLEM)
 
After, I load `I2` into `C2`.
Finally, I set image into `C1` and then `I3.src = C2.toDataURL();` (PROBLEM)

Only in Safari the browser shows in the console the message:

> Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.

I have tried assign the attribute `crossOrigin = ''` and `crossOrigin = 'anonymous'` but it isn't working.

Someone can help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want a real answer show some real code - are any of the images on a different domain than the page itself?

Comment: To use cross origin image, not only setting the `crossOrigin = 'anonymous'` is enough but also the server should support cross origin policy by providing the following headers on its response: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <domain_name>`. Please check that out first. If you share the code that you have tried will be more helpful.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990678/cross-origin-image-load-denied-by-cross-origin-resource-sharing-policy