# How to get screenshot of complete HTML page using HTML2Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using HTML2Canvas  to get image of complete HTML page .I am trying to save that image in PPT on a button click. 
  i am able to save image in PPT.
But the saved image content is getting overlapped and the alert which i have used here is taking around 1 min to show .
when i did debug i got to know that problem is with HTML2Canvas.
i have used many third party charts in my page like Google charts.
can you please suggest me any alternative for HTML2Canvas as i saw there are few limitations in HTML2Canvas when we use cross-origin content.

```
$('#PPTExport').click(function(e) {


var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var target = $('#loadImageHeader');
        html2canvas(target, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {

        var data1 = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");

        alert(data1);




$.ajax({ 
url: "savechart", 
data:{
image1:data1
      }, 

type: 'POST', 
success: function (data) {
if(data=="success")
{

 $("#formid1" ).attr('action','savechartDownload');
 $( "#formid1" ).submit();
}
                           } 
         });

}
});
                                                                    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Have solution for this problem.
You can try this out..

```
 html2canvas([document.body], {
        useCORS: true,
        proxy: "Server",
        onrendered : function(canvas) {                               
             var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
             window.open(myImage);
        }
});
```

**Server** is **server url** of node.js or any language you can write.

Example Node.js : https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas-proxy-nodejs

read more here: [Can't capture google map with html2canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792081/cant-capture-google-map-with-html2canvas)

and Here: [Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990678/cross-origin-image-load-denied-by-cross-origin-resource-sharing-policy)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. can you please provide link to use node.js .

Comment: Where is the proxy file?

Comment: Can i take a screenshot of iframe having external images(Other domain)